Implementing animation curves using cubic bezier curves
I am trying to implement an animation system using cubic bezier curves. It was easy to setup the calculation of the curve itsself. Only evaluating the curve at a specific time x gives me headaches.
I am using KeyFrames which contain the following properties:

Time
Value
InTangent
OutTangent

By using De-Casteljau I can easily calculate the bezier curve at a given value t in [0,1] between 2 of those keyframes.
My current and very naive approach is to calculate t as follows:
var t = (time - currentKeyFrame.Time)/ (nextKeyFrame.Time - currentKeyFrame.Time);

And then I just plug it into the bezier formula. Unfortunately, this does not lead to correct results because t in the bezier calculation does not correspond to the time passed on the x-axis. t is rather the progression value of the bezier curve.
So my question is: is there an efficient/established way you know to get the y-value of a bezier curve at a given x-position rather than using the parameter t of the curve? Or is there even a better approach to implement animation curves?
I've seen that Unity for example supposedly uses Hermite splines for animation curves whereas in the editor you can see that you are editing a standard bezier curve which confuses me. Unfortunately, I haven't had the time to dive deeper into Hermite splines but at a first glance it looks like they do not solve this issue and that there must be some kind of algorithm for that...
An example how I would like to have it implemented is this.

I'd disagree with this: "in the editor you can see that you are editing a standard bezier curve". You're editing a curve that allows you to specify a slope at the start and end points (the direction of the tangent). A cubic Bézier curve allows you to specify a velocity at the start and end points (both direction and length, which the Unity editor does not let you set). So, this is not a Bézier curve, despite the resemblance. A full Bézier curve would let you create non-sensical S paths that cross the same moment in time repeatedly, back and forth, so there's good reason for this restriction.

Yeah it's true that you can't define a fully fledged bezier curve with s paths in the animation curve editor. You can actually also set the length(weight) of the slope but it is restricted so that y-values of the bezier cannot overlap as you mentioned. I was just confused on how those are Hermite splines. My wording probably isn't the best, so sorry for that. It isn't a standard bezier curve, you are right

Did you try the Curve class in MonoGame: https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/blob/develop/MonoGame.Framework/Curve.cs . The Vector2 and Vector3 classes both have hermite spline interpolation. Vector3.Hermite(Vector3 value1, Vector3 tangent1, Vector3 value2, Vector3 tangent2, float amount)

@agone wow I didn't knew this existed. Thanks for sharing!

See also: Cubic Bézier for easing.

I found a solution to the problem. I am really surprised that I had to search for so long but I am happy now.
For anyone who wants to know: this helped me a lot getting it to work.
For anyone interested how to solve this:
We are trying to find the y-coordinate of the Bezier curve at a given x-coordinate. This is essentially a root finding problem. We have to calculate the intersection point of \$b_x(t)\$ and \$x\$.
Graphically, \$x\$ is a horizontal line that intersects with \$b_x(t)\$ exactly once if every \$x\$ value of the Bezier has only one associated \$y\$ value.
$$b_x(t)=a(1-t)^3+3b(1-t)^2t+3c(1-t)^2+dt^3$$
is the formula of the \$x\$ coordinate of the Bezier curve given \$t\$. \$a, b, c\$ and \$d\$ are the \$x\$ coordinates of your control points.
You can rewrite this as:
$$b_x(t)=(-a+3b-3c+d)t^3+(3a-6b+3c)t^2+(-3a+3b)t+a$$
Finally, the equation you have to solve is:
$$\begin{align}(-a+3b-3c+d)t^3+(3a-6b+3c)t^2+(-3a+3b)t+a=x\\
(-a+3b-3c+d)t^3+(3a-6b+3c)t^2+(-3a+3b)t+a-x=0\end{align}$$
Now you can use an algorithm that can find roots for cubic equations. This can for example be Cardano's algorithm. This algorithm also finds complex solutions you can just throw away if you don't need them.
